# Complex SSH tunnel with Go

Tags: go, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Need some help with a tricky SSH tunnel through a bastion host.

I want to port forward Postgres on the remote server, *through* the bastion.  Our company setup only allows communication over SSH, so we have to port forward everything.

Currently, I use the CLI command to set up the SSH tunnel, then use psql shell command on my laptop to query the remote Postgres. I want to write this same connection in Go, so I can create reports, graphs, etc.

The following command line works, but I can't figure out how to do this with Go SSH.

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -l username1 -i ~/.ssh/privKey1.pem bastionIP -W %h:%p"  -i ~/.ssh/privKey2.pem  -L 8080:localhost:5432 -N  username2@PsqlHostIP
psql -h localhost -P 8000 -U user -W pass
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems are you facing?

Comment: More importantly: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Not trying to reinvent the wheel.  I'm trying to automate an awkward manual process

Comment: There are many examples online about how to use go to ssh through a bastion host.  But nothing about how to do a tunnel back through both hosts over SSH.  Hence my question here.